# Upgrading from ASP.NET MVC 3 to MVC 4, parameters being replaced with route

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I recently upgraded my project from MVC3 to MVC4 and since then, some of my action parameters are being passed incorrectly.

The action has this signature:

```
public JsonResult FooAction(int id, int id2, string name, string name2, List<Object1> templates, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary1, Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary2);
```

If the JSON call passes an empty array:

```
"dictionary2":[]
```

Then `dictionary2` is set to the route:

```
{key = "controller", value = "MyController"}
{key = "action", value = "MyAction"}
{key = "id", value = "123123"}
```

Obviously I'd like it to just be an empty dictionary - is there any way I can prevent this behaviour?

[edit] I should mention that I'm using the default routing behaviour:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get needed behavior by adding `[Bind(Prefix = "dictionary2")]` before parameter definition, i.e.

```
public JsonResult FooAction(int id, int id2, string name, string name2, List<Object1> templates, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary1, [Bind(Prefix = "dictionary2")] Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary2);
```

But it beats me too.

Or other way around, by implementing own `ModelBinder`:

```
public class StringDictionaryModelBinderProvider: IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType == typeof (Dictionary<string, string>) || modelType == typeof (IDictionary<string, string>))
            return new StringDictionaryModelBinder();

        return null;
    }

    private class StringDictionaryModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix = false;
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and in application startup:

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new StringDictionaryModelBinderProvider());
```

But still beats me.